# Условие со scanf()

Tags: c, циклы, ввод, scanf

Нужно написать программу, считывающую кол-во минут с начала суток, и последовательность времени вида {HH:MM}, заканчивающаяся пустыми скобками{}. Написал следующую программу, но при вводе, например, 806 {21:00}{12:15}{06:55}{} в цикл while даже не заходит. В чем причина?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct time{
    int h;
    int m;
};

void main(){
    struct time* arr = (struct time*)malloc(100 * sizeof(struct time));
    int size = 100;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int limit;
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    while(scanf("{%d:%d}", &arr[i].h, &arr[i].m) != 0){
        ++i;
        if (i >= size){
            arr = realloc(arr, (size + 100) * sizeof(struct time));
            size += 100;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        if(arr[j].h * 60 + arr[j].m > limit){
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", k);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас во входе после `806` находится пробел (или перевод строки, или какой-то другой пробельный символ). А ваш следующий `scanf` сразу же жестко требует наличия `{` во входе. Встретив во входе пробел вместо `{` второй `scanf` сразу же завершается с ошибкой.

Другими словами, ваш код будет работать правильно, если вы ему на вход дадите

```
806{21:00}{12:15}{06:55}{}
```

Но как только после `806` появляется пробельный символ, ваш второй `scanf` отказывается выполнять чтение.

Вам нужно попросить ваш второй `scanf` пропустить все пробельные символы перед дальнейшим чтением. Для того, чтобы попросить `scanf` пропустить все пробельные символы, в форматную строку надо вставить любой пробельный символ. Например

```
while(scanf(" {%d:%d}", &arr[i].h, &arr[i].m) != 0){
```

Вы можете добавить туда еще несколько пробелов, чтобы сделать формат еще более гибким. Я бы сделал так

```
while(scanf(" {%d :%d }", &arr[i].h, &arr[i].m) != 0){
```

(добавить пробелы *перед* `%d` тоже можно, но это как раз таки не обязательно, т.к. `%d` и так сам по себе пропускает ведущие пробелы).

P. S. `int main(void)`, а не `void main()`. И выделенную память нужно не забывать освобождать.